# python additive probability

Tags: python, scale, probability

I've created a python 2.7 tkinter module which uses scale widget data (aquatic or terrestrial) to influence a tuple which selects between animals. The module sorts and displays the three animals (deer, eel, turtles) in ranked descending order upon clicking 'Submit' and activating the associated command.

```
from Tkinter import (N, S, E, W, BOTH, BOTTOM, END, FLAT, HORIZONTAL, LEFT, NO, RAISED, RIGHT, TOP, YES, Button, Entry, Frame, Grid, Label, Pack, Scale, Text, Tk)

from operator import mul

root = Tk()
root.title('Example')

class Environment:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        # layout
        self.myParent = parent

        self.main_frame = Frame(parent, background="light blue")
        self.main_frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.main_left_frame = Frame(self.main_frame, background="light blue")
        self.main_left_frame.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.main_right_frame = Frame(self.main_frame, background="light blue")
        self.main_right_frame.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.water = Scale(self.main_right_frame, from_=0.01, to=1.00, orient=HORIZONTAL, bd=0, label="Aquatic",
        background="white", troughcolor="cyan", length=50, width=10, sliderlength=10, resolution=0.01)
        self.water.pack()
        self.water.set(1.00)

        self.soil = Scale(self.main_right_frame, from_=0.01, to=1.00, orient=HORIZONTAL, bd=0, label="Terrestrial",
        background="white", troughcolor="saddle brown", length=50, width=10, sliderlength=10, resolution=0.01)
        self.soil.pack()
        self.soil.set(1.00)

        self.id_frame = Frame(self.main_left_frame, background="white")
        self.id_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        # submit button
        self.submitbutton = Button(self.main_left_frame,text="Submit", background="black", foreground="white",
        width=6, padx="2m", pady="1m")
        self.submitbutton.pack(side=TOP)
        self.submitbutton.bind("<Button-1>", self.submitbuttonclick)
        self.submitbutton.bind("<Return>", self.submitbuttonclick)

        #Animal Matrix
        self.animal = [
        ('Odocoileous virginiana','White-tailed Deer',self.soil.get,0.99,0.01,0.99),
        ('Anguilla anguilla','American Eel',self.water.get,0.99,0.01,0.99),
        ('Trachemys scripta','Red-eared Slider',lambda:self.soil.get()*self.water.get(),0.99,0.01,0.99)]

    def submitbuttonclick(self, event):
        self.id_frame.destroy()
        self.id_frame = Frame(self.main_left_frame, background="white")
        self.id_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        A=self.animal

        #equation
        sigma = float(sum(reduce(mul,item[3:]) for item in A))
        B = [(item[0], "%.2f" % (item[2]()*reduce(mul, item[3:])/sigma)) for item in A]
        C = sorted(B, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)  

        Label(self.id_frame, text = C[0], background = "white").pack(side=TOP, anchor = W)
        Label(self.id_frame, text = C[1], background = "white").pack(side=TOP, anchor = W)
        Label(self.id_frame, text = C[2], background = "white").pack(side=TOP, anchor = W)

environment = Environment(root)       
root.mainloop()
```

In theory, sliding the aquatic scale to 0.01 should eliminate the eel (Eel: 0.00) and sliding the terrestrial scale to 0.01 should eliminate the deer (Deer: 0.00).  This works fine.

However, when dealing with an animal that is both aquatic and terrestrial, the code falls apart.  The turtle should not hit zero so long as either the aquatic or terrestrial scale is above 0.01.  Additive probability doesn't work.

```
lambda:self.soil.get()*self.water.get()
```

How do I express this so that both are considered but neither can cancel out the other?

Comment: Please distil this code down to the essentials for your question.

Comment: This is distilled.  This is a bare minimum example--notice the root.title--specifically created to ask this and a few related questions regarding tweaking issues I've been having with a much larger module.  Is 100 lines really so much to scroll down--most of which are widget descriptions in a question about scale widgets?  Would providing lambda:self.soil.get()*self.water.get() have been very helpful without proper context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probabilities are funny things.  To combine these probabilities you need to look at the probability that it is *not* terrestial and it is *not* aquatic.  Then take 1 minus that combined probability.  The code for the turtle would look like this.

```
('Trachemys scripta','Red-eared Slider',lambda:1-(1-self.soil.get())*(1-self.water.get()),0.99,0.01,0.99)]
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a life saver.  I'm going to go smack myself on the forehead for not having puzzled that one out myself.

Comment: Addendum.  If you use lambda over and over again for a large tuple with 15+ rows, you'll run out of memory fast and the module will refuse to run.  Linking it to a local variable such as soilandwater=lambda:1-(1-self.soil.get())*(1-self.water.get()) and putting the variable soilandwater into your tuple fixes the memory hog issue